# SharePoint 2013 Content Search and Refinement Panel

Tags: search, search-results, fast-search, enterprise-search, refinement-panel

I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise search. My search page has a Search Textbox, Refinement Panel and the search results web part.

When I perform a content search my matching search results are displayed, I then can use the refinement panel to further refine my results based on the content search results. Perfect, no problem there.

BUT, if I start my search using a refinement panel and then want to search content (Using my textbox search) that is based on the results from my refinement panel, I cant. Once I do a textbox search the results are for all matching documents not just the results from my initial refinement results.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible - the searchbox overrides the refinement.

The idea behind it is: The end-user starts searching by using a phrase/keyword in the textbox - then he **refines** the result set with the refiners.

Comment: You can however modify the behavior with script or similar, but you would need other UI changes to make the users understand how to clear the search and start from scratch.